# How to remove node by value on d3 tree?

Tags: d3.js, tree

I would like to remove nodes that have 0 as "cardinalita". 
For now I have hidden nodes but I would like remove empty link.

Here the situation:
https://jsfiddle.net/d65k3zzy/

```js
        var treeData = [
          {
            "name": "First",
            "parent": "null",
   "cardinalita": "9",
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "Second",
                "parent": "First",
    "cardinalita": "1",
                "children": [
       {
      "name": "Third",
      "parent": "Second",
      "cardinalita": "63",
      "children": [
        {
       "name": "fourth",
       "parent": "Third",
       "cardinalita": "39",
       "children": [
         {
        "name": "last",
        "parent": "fourth",
        "cardinalita": "70",
        "children": [
          {
         "name": "special",
         "parent": "last",
         "cardinalita": "11"
          }
        ]
         },
         {
        "name": "special",
        "parent": "fourth",
        "cardinalita": "0"
         }
       ]
        },
        {
       "name": "null",
       "parent": "Third",
       "cardinalita": "0",
       "children": [
         {
        "name": "special",
        "parent": "null",
        "cardinalita": "10"
         }
       ]
        }
      ]
       },
       {
     "name": "Third",
     "parent": "Second",
     "cardinalita": "528"
      }
                ]
              },
     {
                "name": "Second",
                "parent": "First",
    "cardinalita": "33",
                "children": [
      {
     "name": "Third",
     "parent": "Second",
     "cardinalita": "63"
      }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ];


        // ************** Generate the tree diagram  *****************
        var margin = {top: 0, right: 120, bottom: 40, left: 60},
            width = 1000 - margin.right - margin.left,
            height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
            
        var i = 0,
            duration = 750,
            root;
        
        var tree = d3.layout.tree()
            // distanza fra i nodi figli
            .separation(function separation(a, b) { return a.parent == b.parent ? 1.5 : 1; })
            .size([height, width]);

        
        var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
            .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });
        
        var svg = d3.select("#diagramma").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
          .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
        
        root = treeData[0];
        root.x0 = height / 2;
        root.y0 = 0;
          
        update(root);
        
        d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "500px");
        
        function update(source) {
         
          // Compute the new tree layout.
          var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
              links = tree.links(nodes);

          // Normalize for fixed-depth.
          nodes.forEach(function(d) {  d.y = d.depth * 160; });
        
          // Update the nodes…
          var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
              .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });
        
          // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
          var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
              .attr("class", "node")
              .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
              //.on("click", click);
        
          // contenitore testo
          nodeEnter.append("svg:rect")
 
      .attr("width", function(d) { if(d.name != 'null' || (d.cardinalita < 1)){return "70";} })
      .attr("height", function (d) {
       return 21;
     })
      .attr("r", 1e-6)
      .attr("y", -10)
      .attr("x", -50)
      .attr("rx", 0)
      .attr("ry", 0)
      .attr("stroke", function(d) { if(d.name != 'null' && d.cardinalita >= 1){return "#23527c";} })
      
      .attr("stroke-width", "2")
      .style("fill", function (d) {
       return d._children ? "#ccc" : "#fff";
      })
      .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { if(d.name == 'null' || (d.cardinalita < 1)){return "0";} })
     
    //contenitore cardinalità
          nodeEnter.append("svg:rect")
              
              .attr("width", 25)
              .attr("height", function (d) {
                  return 21;
                })
              .attr("r", 1e-6)
              .attr("y", 11)
              .attr("x", -5)
              .attr("rx", 0)
              .attr("ry", 0)
              .attr("stroke", function(d) { if(d.name != 'null' && d.cardinalita >= 1){return "#23527c";} })
              .attr("stroke-width", "2")
              .style("fill", "#fff")
     .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { if(d.name == 'null' || (d.cardinalita < 1)){return "0";} })
              
          // nome del nodo
          nodeEnter.append("text")
              .attr("x", function (d) {
                  return d._children ? -8 : 8;
              })
              .attr("y", -4)
              .attr("x", -40)
              .attr("dy", "0.7em")
              .style("font-size", "14")
     .style("font-weight", "bold")
              .text(function (d) {
    if(d.name != 'null' && d.cardinalita != 0)
                  return d.name;

              });
     
          // cardinalità
          nodeEnter.append("text")
              .attr("x", function (d) {
                  return d._children ? -8 : 8;
              })
              .attr("y", 18)
              .attr("x", -2)
              .attr("dy", "0.7em")
              .style("font-size", "14")
              .text(function (d) {
      if(d.name != 'null' && d.cardinalita >= 1)
                   return d.cardinalita;
              });
     

          // Transition nodes to their new position.
          var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
              .duration(duration)
              .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });
        
          nodeUpdate.select("rect")
              .attr("r", 10)
              .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });
        
          nodeUpdate.select("text")
              .style("fill-opacity", 1);
        
          // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
          var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
              .duration(duration)
              .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
              .remove();
        
          nodeExit.select("rect")
              .attr("r", 1e-6);
        
          nodeExit.select("text")
              .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);
        
          // Update the links…
          var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
              .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });
        
          // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
          link.enter().insert("path", "g")
              .attr("class", "link")
              .attr("d", function(d) {
                var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
                return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
              });
        
          // Transition links to their new position.
          link.transition()
              .duration(duration)
              .attr("d", diagonal);
        
          // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
          link.exit().transition()
              .duration(duration)
              .attr("d", function(d) {
                var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
                return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
              })
              .remove();
        
          // Stash the old positions for transition.
          nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
          });
        }
 
  // Toggle children on click.
  function click(d) {
    if (d.children) {
   d._children = d.children;
   d.children = null;
    } else {
   d.children = d._children;
   d._children = null;
    }
    update(d);
  }
```

```css
header { padding: 20px; }
 section { overflow: hidden; width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto;}

 .node text {
   font: 12px sans-serif;
 }

 .link {
   fill: none;
   stroke: #ccc;
   stroke-width: 2px;
 }
 #diagramma { display: inline; float: left; }
 .map { display: inline; float: right; }
  
 .p {
   font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
   text-align: center;
 }
 
 .map svg {
   height: auto;
   width: auto;
   min-width: 300px;
   max-width: 400px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   display: block;
 }
 
 .map g {
   fill: #ccc;
   stroke: #fff;
   stroke-width: 2;
 }
 
 .map g:hover, g.active, .st0:hover, .active .st0 {
   fill: #23527c !important;
   cursor: help;
   cursor: pointer;
 }
 
 .info_panel {
   background-color: rgba(255,255,255, .8);
   padding: 5px;
   font-size: 12px;
   font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
   position: absolute;
   border: 1px solid #333;
   color: #333;
   white-space: nowrap;
 }
 
 .info_panel::first-line {
   font-weight: bold;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <section>
     <div id="diagramma">
        </div> 
    </section>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you really want to remove links that have `cardinalita === "0"` and have no children:

```
      // Transition links to their new position.
      link.transition()
          .duration(duration)
          .attr("d", function(d){
             if (!d.target.children && d.target.cardinalita === "0")
               return "M0,0"; //<-- draw nothing
             else
               return diagonal(d);
          });
```

Full code:

```js
        var treeData = [
          {
            "name": "First",
            "parent": "null",
   "cardinalita": "9",
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "Second",
                "parent": "First",
    "cardinalita": "1",
                "children": [
       {
      "name": "Third",
      "parent": "Second",
      "cardinalita": "63",
      "children": [
        {
       "name": "fourth",
       "parent": "Third",
       "cardinalita": "39",
       "children": [
         {
        "name": "last",
        "parent": "fourth",
        "cardinalita": "70",
        "children": [
          {
         "name": "special",
         "parent": "last",
         "cardinalita": "11"
          }
        ]
         },
         {
        "name": "special",
        "parent": "fourth",
        "cardinalita": "0"
         }
       ]
        },
        {
       "name": "null",
       "parent": "Third",
       "cardinalita": "0",
       "children": [
         {
        "name": "special",
        "parent": "null",
        "cardinalita": "10"
         }
       ]
        }
      ]
       },
       {
     "name": "Third",
     "parent": "Second",
     "cardinalita": "528"
      }
                ]
              },
     {
                "name": "Second",
                "parent": "First",
    "cardinalita": "33",
                "children": [
      {
     "name": "Third",
     "parent": "Second",
     "cardinalita": "63"
      }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ];


        // ************** Generate the tree diagram  *****************
        var margin = {top: 0, right: 120, bottom: 40, left: 60},
            width = 1000 - margin.right - margin.left,
            height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
            
        var i = 0,
            duration = 750,
            root;
        
        var tree = d3.layout.tree()
            // distanza fra i nodi figli
            .separation(function separation(a, b) { return a.parent == b.parent ? 1.5 : 1; })
            .size([height, width]);

        
        var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
            .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });
        
        var svg = d3.select("#diagramma").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
          .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
        
        root = treeData[0];
        root.x0 = height / 2;
        root.y0 = 0;
          
        update(root);
        
        d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "500px");
        
        function update(source) {
         
          // Compute the new tree layout.
          var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
              links = tree.links(nodes);

          // Normalize for fixed-depth.
          nodes.forEach(function(d) {  d.y = d.depth * 160; });
        
          // Update the nodes…
          var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
              .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });
        
          // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
          var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
              .attr("class", "node")
              .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
              //.on("click", click);
        
          // contenitore testo
          nodeEnter.append("svg:rect")
 
      .attr("width", function(d) { if(d.name != 'null' || (d.cardinalita < 1)){return "70";} })
      .attr("height", function (d) {
       return 21;
     })
      .attr("r", 1e-6)
      .attr("y", -10)
      .attr("x", -50)
      .attr("rx", 0)
      .attr("ry", 0)
      .attr("stroke", function(d) { if(d.name != 'null' && d.cardinalita >= 1){return "#23527c";} })
      
      .attr("stroke-width", "2")
      .style("fill", function (d) {
       return d._children ? "#ccc" : "#fff";
      })
      .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { if(d.name == 'null' || (d.cardinalita < 1)){return "0";} })
     
    //contenitore cardinalità
          nodeEnter.append("svg:rect")
              
              .attr("width", 25)
              .attr("height", function (d) {
                  return 21;
                })
              .attr("r", 1e-6)
              .attr("y", 11)
              .attr("x", -5)
              .attr("rx", 0)
              .attr("ry", 0)
              .attr("stroke", function(d) { if(d.name != 'null' && d.cardinalita >= 1){return "#23527c";} })
              .attr("stroke-width", "2")
              .style("fill", "#fff")
     .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { if(d.name == 'null' || (d.cardinalita < 1)){return "0";} })
              
          // nome del nodo
          nodeEnter.append("text")
              .attr("x", function (d) {
                  return d._children ? -8 : 8;
              })
              .attr("y", -4)
              .attr("x", -40)
              .attr("dy", "0.7em")
              .style("font-size", "14")
     .style("font-weight", "bold")
              .text(function (d) {
    if(d.name != 'null' && d.cardinalita != 0)
                  return d.name;

              });
     
          // cardinalità
          nodeEnter.append("text")
              .attr("x", function (d) {
                  return d._children ? -8 : 8;
              })
              .attr("y", 18)
              .attr("x", -2)
              .attr("dy", "0.7em")
              .style("font-size", "14")
              .text(function (d) {
      if(d.name != 'null' && d.cardinalita >= 1)
                   return d.cardinalita;
              });
     

          // Transition nodes to their new position.
          var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
              .duration(duration)
              .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });
        
          nodeUpdate.select("rect")
              .attr("r", 10)
              .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });
        
          nodeUpdate.select("text")
              .style("fill-opacity", 1);
        
          // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
          var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
              .duration(duration)
              .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
              .remove();
        
          nodeExit.select("rect")
              .attr("r", 1e-6);
        
          nodeExit.select("text")
              .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);
        
          // Update the links…
          var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
              .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });
        
          // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
          link.enter().insert("path", "g")
              .attr("class", "link");
                     
          // Transition links to their new position.
          link.transition()
              .duration(duration)
              .attr("d", function(d){
                 if (!d.target.children && d.target.cardinalita === "0")
                   return "M0,0";
                 else
                  return diagonal(d);
              });
        
          // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
          link.exit().transition()
              .duration(duration)
              .attr("d", function(d) {
                var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
                return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
              })
              .remove();
        
          // Stash the old positions for transition.
          nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
          });
        }
 
  // Toggle children on click.
  function click(d) {
    if (d.children) {
   d._children = d.children;
   d.children = null;
    } else {
   d.children = d._children;
   d._children = null;
    }
    update(d);
  }
```

```css
header { padding: 20px; }
 section { overflow: hidden; width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto;}

 .node text {
   font: 12px sans-serif;
 }

 .link {
   fill: none;
   stroke: #ccc;
   stroke-width: 2px;
 }
 #diagramma { display: inline; float: left; }
 .map { display: inline; float: right; }
  
 .p {
   font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
   text-align: center;
 }
 
 .map svg {
   height: auto;
   width: auto;
   min-width: 300px;
   max-width: 400px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   display: block;
 }
 
 .map g {
   fill: #ccc;
   stroke: #fff;
   stroke-width: 2;
 }
 
 .map g:hover, g.active, .st0:hover, .active .st0 {
   fill: #23527c !important;
   cursor: help;
   cursor: pointer;
 }
 
 .info_panel {
   background-color: rgba(255,255,255, .8);
   padding: 5px;
   font-size: 12px;
   font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
   position: absolute;
   border: 1px solid #333;
   color: #333;
   white-space: nowrap;
 }
 
 .info_panel::first-line {
   font-weight: bold;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <body>
    <section>
     <div id="diagramma">
        </div> 
    </section>
  </body>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you Mark for answer. I see just a issue in your solution:

when tree diagramm drawing, the links are not animated

Comment: Ok, I've just changed to my code link.transition() function and now work great. THANK YOU